# Merge some list items in a Python List

Tags: python, list, concatenation

Say I have a list like this:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

How do modify that list so that it looks like this?

```
[a, b, c, def, g]
```

I would much prefer that it modified the existing list directly, not created a new list.

Comment: On what basis should the merging take place?

Comment: What are a, b, etc. (i.e. what data type)? As it stands, typing this into a Python interpreter gives an error because these are unbound names.

Comment: Do you always want those items in the list concatenated, or do you want to be able to choose where and how many later?

Answer (score 73):

On what basis should the merging take place? Your question is rather vague. Also, I assume a, b, ..., f are supposed to be strings, that is, 'a', 'b', ..., 'f'.

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> x[3:6] = [''.join(x[3:6])]
>>> x
['a', 'b', 'c', 'def', 'g']
```

Check out the documentation on [sequence types](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range), specifically on [mutable sequence types](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). And perhaps also on [string methods](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Answer (score 41):

That example is pretty vague, but maybe something like this?

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
items[3:6] = [''.join(items[3:6])]
```

It basically does a splice (or [assignment to a slice](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)) operation. It removes items 3 to 6 and inserts a new list in their place (in this case a list with one item, which is the concatenation of the three items that were removed.)

For any type of list, you could do this (using the `+` operator on all items no matter what their type is):

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
items[3:6] = [reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, items[3:6])]
```

This makes use of the [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce) function with a [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#lambda) function that basically adds the items together using the `+` operator.

Comment: This works great for a list of strings.  If the elements aren't strings, you'll need to use something other than ''.join()

Comment: You're right, I added an example using `reduce` which works for any type of item that supports the `+` operator. I can't do more than that unless the OP expands on his question.

Comment: His question doesn't really make sense for anything else than strings.

Comment: upvoted for the generic solution with reduce - although the question only seems to make sense for strings, the general solution to appending all elements of a list with one another is a great one.

Answer (score 5):

just a variation

```
alist=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 0, "g"]
alist[3:6] = [''.join(map(str,alist[3:6]))]
print alist
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course @Stephan202 has given a really nice answer. I am providing an alternative.

```
def compressx(min_index = 3, max_index = 6, x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']):
    x = x[:min_index] + [''.join(x[min_index:max_index])] + x[max_index:]
    return x
compressx()

>>>['a', 'b', 'c', 'def', 'g']
```

You can also do the following.

```
x = x[:min_index] + [''.join(x[min_index:max_index])] + x[max_index:]
print(x)

>>>['a', 'b', 'c', 'def', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

my telepathic abilities are not particularly great, but here is what I think you want:

```
def merge(list_of_strings, indices):
    list_of_strings[indices[0]] = ''.join(list_of_strings[i] for i in indices)
    list_of_strings = [s for i, s in enumerate(list_of_strings) if i not in indices[1:]]
    return list_of_strings
```

I should note, since it might be not obvious, that it's not the same as what is proposed in other answers.