# Merging list n items into one item in python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list where each item contain a string of considerable length, example:

```
mylist = [
    'this is my string number one it is much longer than that',
    'this is my string two it is much longer than that',
    # ...
]
```

I want to join all of those items in all indices of this list, into
one item only, so items in indices from 0 to n, shall all be combined
to index 0. I tried this (
[Merge some list items in a Python List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142851/merge-some-list-items-in-a-python-list)
) but it did not work for me, I get no error, but my list items are
not merged?

I have also tried this code:

```
final = []
for item in mylist:
    final.append(''.join(item))
```

But it still gives me the same output, no joined list items at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply `str.join()` to the *whole list*, not to each item:

```
final = [''.join(mylist)]
```

I've put the result back into a list with one item.

The other question was trying to join *some* of the elements in the input list, which is why `str.join()` was applied to `x[3:6]` there.